# Process from CSV files and load them into Cassandra using Java

Tags: java, database, csv, cassandra

For a CSV file, each line is one record, and formatted like this:

```
'dataOne1,dataOne2,dataOne3','dataTwo1,dataTwo2','dataThree1,dataThree2,dataThree3,dataThree4'
```

Basically, the quotes break the data string into different parts(three parts this time), and in each part, the data is divided by a coma. Is there an efficient way (we have tons of such data lines to process) to parse each line and get the data in different part for later use? Finally, these data will go into the Cassandra database. Regular Expression? Or any other advice will be appreciated. I am using Java.

Comment: http://techie-matter.blogspot.com/2014/02/exportimport-data-in-cassandra-table.html

Comment: and this link provides java code :http://prashantguptaimpetus.blogspot.com/2013/02/bulk-insert-in-cassandra.html

Comment: it seems that this method is for small sets of datum. But our company has tons of lines in csv files to process...

Comment: Ok, use cassandra bulk loader , this link provides JMX implementation:pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2012/06/bulk-loading-data-to-cassandra-using.html